# Exclude (conditional) linked source files from code coverage

Tags: c#, .net, testing, code-coverage, xunit

I'm using VS2022 Community Edition with [Fine Code Coverage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FortuneNgwenya.FineCodeCoverage) and xUnit for unit testing. I would like the following linked source files in .csproj file to be excluded from testing code coverage:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\Argument.IReadOnlyLIst.VerifyNotEmpty.cs" Link="ref\common\Argument.IReadOnlyLIst.VerifyNotEmpty.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\Argument.IReadOnlyList.VerifyNotNull.cs" Link="ref\common\Argument.IReadOnlyList.VerifyNotNull.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\Argument.VerifyNotNull.cs" Link="ref\common\Argument.VerifyNotNull.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\Object.GetObjectDisposedException.cs" Link="ref\common\Object.GetObjectDisposedException.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\String.VerifyNotEmpty.cs" Link="ref\common\String.VerifyNotEmpty.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\Type.GetStaticMethodInfo.cs" Link="ref\common\Type.GetStaticMethodInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\Type.ResolveStaticGetter.cs" Link="ref\common\Type.ResolveStaticGetter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\IReadOnlyList.IndexOf.cs" Link="ref\common\IReadOnlyList.IndexOf.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\AppendOnlyList.cs" Link="ref\common\AppendOnlyList.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\ListOfT.MoveRange.cs" Link="ref\common\LIstOfT.MoveRange.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="('$(TargetFramework)' != 'netstandard2.0' and '$(TargetFramework)' != 'net461')">
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.cs" Link="ref\common\System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\ref\common\UInt32.AppendTo.cs" Link="ref\common\UInt32.AppendTo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

These files are shared under `ref` folder and are tested separately.

The following is the dependent snippet of testing .csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Edit:
I tried adding a CodeCoverage.runsettings XML file to the solution:

```
<Sources>
  <Exclude>
     <Source>.*\\ref\\common\\.*</Source>
  </Exclude>
</Sources>
```

but with no luck:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work by adding a CodeCoverage.runsettings file as a solution item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- File name extension must be .runsettings -->
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat code coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <ExcludeByFile>**/ref/**/*</ExcludeByFile>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

What I didn't know is xUnit and MSTest are using different `DataCollector`.